# Machine-specific gvim customization file tree with otherwise minimal customization?

Tags: gvim

I upgraded my Cygwin X-windows after 5 years. I found that there is no
more `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles`, so I copied my files from the `after`,
`colors`, `plugin`, `spell`, and `syntax` folders directly into the
corresponding folders in `/usr/share/vim/vim81`.  This is far from
ideal, as it doesn't separate my custoimization files from the gvim
package files.

*What is the most robust way to maintain a separate tree of
customization files, i.e., with minimal customization of environmental
variables and paths?  Is there a default location where gvim looks for
a site-specific file tree that differs from the packaged ones?*

**Context**

Like most people, my laptop is primarily used by myself. The different
accounts are only so that I can work with a non-administrator account
for normal stuff, i.e., not maintenance or housekeeping.  In both
administrator and non-administrator accounts, I want the same vim
environment.  Therefore, I will not be using user-specific vimrc
files, run time paths, etc.  These will be system-wide, hence my
description of the situation as a site/machine-specific setup.

**What I've found so far**

I found relevant factors from `:help startup`.  By default, my Cygwin
installation does not set up $VIM, $VIMINIT, or $MYVIMRC.  In this
situation, according to the help, all folders in the `runtimepath`
(`rtp`) setting are searched for plugins.  Fortunately,
`/usr/share/vim/vimfiles` precedes `/usr/share/vim/vim81` in my `rtp`:

```
runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim81,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after
```

The leading `~/vim` is a holdover from an old user-specific vimrc
file, before I decided to do things system-wide.  It led to headaches
keeping the various vimrc files synchronized.  I'm going to leave it
in because there may be occassion to take advantage of it, but I just
won't have a ~/vim by default.

Because it is present in `rtp`
all I have to do create `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles`  and unpack my
personal `after`, `colors`, `plugin`, `spell`, and `syntax` folders
directly into it.  According to `:help rtp`, all of these folders
are searched for in the paths specified by `rtp`.

It looks like I've answered my own question, but I'd appreciate it if
someone could confirm its correctness.

**Mitigating pollution of virgin vim 8.1 package files**

It's too late for me now.  I already polluted the
`/usr/share/vim/vim81` file tree with my custom files.  However, I
think I just selectively copied files into locations wherein they did
not exist.  I can use bash to find the relative paths 
of my customization files in the `vim81` tree

```
cd /path/to/my/customization/file/tree
for file in $( find * -type f )
do
    diff -qs $file /usr/share/vim/vim81/$file
done

Files after/ftplugin/netrw.vim and ../vim81/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim are identical
Files after/syntax/tex.vim and ../vim81/after/syntax/tex.vim are identical
Files colors/mine.vim and ../vim81/colors/mine.vim are identical
Files plugin/bufexplorer.vim and ../vim81/plugin/bufexplorer.vim are identical
Files plugin/ChristiansHi20150126.vim and ../vim81/plugin/ChristiansHi20150126.vim are identical
diff: ../vim81/spell/en.latin1.add: No such file or directory
diff: ../vim81/syntax/asy.vim: No such file or directory
Files syntax/texmf.vim and ../vim81/syntax/texmf.vim differ
diff: ../vim81/syntax/vbnet.vim: No such file or directory
```

Every occurrence of `..` represents the absolute path
`/user/share/vim`.  The only files I copied into the `vim81` tree are
those found to be identical.  If there is no corresponding file in the
`vim81` tree, it means I dispensed with copying that file because
there seemed to be another file with a different name but for the same
purpose, and more recent.  On the other hand, if the files with the same name differed in content, it means I chose to
rely on the newer file in the `vim81` tree.

My custom files now exist in both `vim81` and `vimfiles`.  The command
`:scriptnames` shows that the occurrence in `vimfiles` precedes the
occurrence in `vim81`.  This is good, but still redundant.  I can
repeat the above code pattern to locate the redundant occurrences in
`vim81`, extract their paths, and submit them to the remove command
`rm`:

```
cd /usr/share/vim/vimfiles
for file in $(find * -type f); do diff -qs $file ../vim81/$file; done 2>&1 | grep identical | sed -e 's=.* \(\S\+\) are identical=\1=' | xargs rm
```

As this is now a system-wide custoimization, I had to ensure that all
accounts had read access to files/folders in `vimfiles`, and all execution
rights to directories therein (so that they can actually descend into them):

```
cd /usr/share/vim

# Directories
find vimfiles -type d | xargs chmod a+rx,o-w
find vimfiles/ -type d | xargs ls -ldF # Visually confirm permissions

# Files
find vimfiles -type f | xargs chmod a-x,a+r
find vimfiles/ -type f | xargs ls -ldF # Visually confirm permissions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have figured out, even though a `vimfiles` directory isn't shipped as part of the Vim package in Cygwin, if you create one and populate it, Vim (and gVim) will use it in its search path.

This is controlled by the `'runtimepath'` setting. And [`:help 'runtimepath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html?#%27runtimepath%27) confirms that the default is:

> ```
>            Unix: "$HOME/.vim,
>                   $VIM/vimfiles,
>                   $VIMRUNTIME,
>                   $VIM/vimfiles/after,
>                   $HOME/.vim/after"
> ```

Cygwin is Unix emulation on Windows, so the Unix defaults are used.

The order of entries in your `'runtimepath'` corresponds exactly to the default. (You mentioned `~/.vim` as a holdover from an old user-specific vimrc file, but that's actually the default, I don't think you're customizing these. If you are, maybe you don't need to. It's also normal that `vimfiles` and `vimfiles/after` come before and after `$VIMRUNTIME`, so that your files will have the correct priority.)

It is normal for the `$VIM`, `$VIMRUNTIME` and similar environment variables *not* to be set. (In effect, I haven't ever seen a situation in which those are set outside of Vim.) They're typically initialized by Vim itself. See [`:help $VIM`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html?#%24VIM) for details on how these are set up.

Installing your custom files under `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles` is a good approach. As you also found out, you need to ensure they're world-readable, since all users will try to source them.

Regarding keeping your Cygwin installation pristine, you can try to reinstall the package that owns the Vim runtime files (I imagine the package might be called `vim-runtime` or similar.) From Cygwin's `setup.exe` you can manage Cygwin's packages and there's an option to reinstall a specific package. For complete cleanup, try to *uninstall* the package that ships the Vim runtimes, then remove any files left in `/usr/share/vim/vim81` and finally installing that package back. (There's also a `cygcheck` command you can use to inspect packages in Cygwin.)

Installing, reinstalling or checking Cygwin packages is a bit off topic for Vi &Vim, consider asking on [Superuser Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/) if you have any follow up questions about Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, filbranden. You're right, my code didn't add `~/.vim` to `runtimepath`.  I have code that does it, but surrounded by flow control so that it runs only for the Windows installation of gvim (which I no longer use due to lack of bash integration).  I appreciate your suggestions on keeping the installation files pristine, but I'm comfortable with how I located and removed custom files from `vim81`.  I don't want to tempt fate by messing further.